# magento how to get search query

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I want get search query in magento. But i don't know where to get it. For example if I try searching with `T-shirt`. magento will search that term and return back the results which is match. For this magento search the string in database like,

```
SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2...
[WHERE condition1 [AND [OR]] condition2.....
```

So I want this search query. Anybody know how to get the final sql query please ?

Comment: What? you want to find location of file containing query?

Comment: yeah, I just want print that query.

Comment: I have experience with Joomla but not with Magento ... probably look at the URL in the browser and then determine what View or Model it is being executed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento collecting data with lot of internal queries - models and lot of checks, and may be more than 1 table.  So it is not possible to get the query like what I'm looking for.

But we can get the collection query using,

```
Mage::log((string)$collection->getSelect(),null,'test.log',true);
```

or just print,

```
$Collection->printLogQuery(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the files related to the search here in this folder app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/ . Magento search save queries for the future and results for caching and statistics. Make your query to join the product collection with the search result table. More you can find in this file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Engine.php

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew this. The problem is I can't able to view what sql query to be ran finally.

Comment: If you have got the related files you can use the print_r and die() to get the exact query which is running.